# Fix IE/Edge CSS clip-path

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, clip-path

I'm having troubles with clip-path property with IE11/Edge browsers while using clip-path CSS property.

The snippet below is what I have so far and is working good in all browsers, apart Microsoft ones.
I cannot understand how to solve this.

```css
.banner {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/435/2000/800.jpg");
}

.banner-clickable {
  margin: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 35%, 0% 75%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

.banner-clickable:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.banner::after, .banner::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ee3b26, #ee3b26);
  cursor: auto;
}

.banner::before {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 35%, calc(100% + 1px) 0%);
}

.banner:after {
  clip-path:  polygon(0% 75%, 0% calc(100% + 1px), calc(100% + 1px) calc(100% + 1px));
  background: #fff
}

.banner > * {
  z-index: 100;
}

.banner {
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 72vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-clickable"></div>
  <div class="scrollBt">
    <a href="#content" class="scroll">LINK</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

And a jsfiddle to help: [JsFille](https://jsfiddle.net/superforno/fth2j7k9/12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 11 only supports the CSS `clip-path` property [in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path). It's hard to make it exactly the same in IE 11 like using `clip-path` in other modern browsers. I think the easiest way is to use an image in IE, the image should be the same as the outcome of applying css styles in other browsers. I use a image [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpNAO.jpg) and target the css styles with no IE browsers:

```css
@supports not (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
/* Non-IE styles here */
  #photo {
    display: none;
  }
  .banner {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/435/2000/800.jpg");
  }
  .banner-clickable {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 35%, 0% 75%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  .banner-clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .banner::after,
  .banner::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ee3b26, #ee3b26);
    cursor: auto;
  }
  .banner::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 35%, calc(100% + 1px) 0%);
  }
  .banner:after {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 75%, 0% calc(100% + 1px), calc(100% + 1px) calc(100% + 1px));
    background: #fff
  }
  .banner>* {
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .banner {
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 72vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-clickable"></div>
  <div class="scrollBt">
    <a href="#content" class="scroll">LINK</a>
  </div>
  <div id="photo" style="position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px; z-index:-999;">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpNAO.jpg" style="width:100%" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, probably this will be the best-effort compatibility fix I can do.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected not to work on IE / Edge since `clip-path` is not supported by them, see more details at [Can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

You can check if you can safely use a css property/selector accross the browsers in the site above.

Comment: Yes, I see that, my question is more about how to fix this in IE/Edge, where clip-path is not supported.

Comment: You can search for a workaround, but my advice is that it is not worthy. It will take time and most of the time won't work as you wish simply because those browsers can't do it. The best solution, in my opinion, is to make a "Wonderful" site for the browsers that support it and a "Great" site for those who don't.